# Getting NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to flutter firebase and I am getting this error `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null flutter`. I have searched and looked very carefully but left scratching my head only where is the error. Over on my condition I'm checking if user is not equal to null then save it but its not happening.
Here's my phone authentication file code which should save the user as well but its not doing it right now because of the null issue

```
class PhoneAuthService {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  Future<void> addUser(context, uid) async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await users.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> document = result.docs;
    if (document.length > 0) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LocationScreen.id);
    } else {
      return users.doc(user.uid).set({
        'uid': user.uid,
        'mobile': user.phoneNumber,
        'email': user.email,
      }).then((value) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LocationScreen.id);
      }).catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
    }
  }

  Future<void> verifyPhonenumber(BuildContext context, number) async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
      await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    };
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
        print('The phone number is not valid');
      }
      print("The error is ${e.code}");
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verId, int resendToken) async {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OTPScreen(
                    number: number,
                    verId: verId,
                  )));
    };

    try {
      auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: number,
          verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
          verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
          codeSent: codeSent,
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
            print(verificationId);
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }
}
```

This is where I'm getting the user otp and proceeding it further

```
Future<void> phoneCredential(BuildContext context, String otp) async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: widget.verId, smsCode: otp);
      final User user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      if (user != null) {
        _services.addUser(context, user.uid);
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LocationScreen.id);
      } else {
        print("Login Process Failed ");
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            error = 'Login Failed';
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          error = 'Invalid OTP';
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

If anyone understood where I'm doing wrong please help I'm stuck for 3 days on it now.

Comment: In what line of your code this error is throw?

Comment: _services.addUser(context, user.uid);

Comment: what happend if you replace this code: if (user != null) {...} for this if (user.uid != null) {...}

Comment: stays the same NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6061): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6061): Tried calling: uid